# Spring passing data from an AuthenticationFailureHandler to a controller

Tags: java, spring, model-view-controller, controller

I am a beginner in Spring MVC and I am wondering if there's a design pattern for the following. 
I have an ExceptionMappingAuthenticationFailureHandler that redirects users to a page if their password has expired, but I need to save the username somewhere before they are redirected and I can't attach that on the URL as a query parameter.

How do I pass the information to the controller? I am asking for a proper way, since setting session attributes is messy and I will have to use Flash redirect which is not available from the handler

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you have to pass it explicitly. It should be available through the `Principal` user.

```
@RequestMapping(...)
public String controllerMethod(Principal principal[,...]) {...}
```

Comment: Since the use is not authenticated yet (because of an expired password), principal will be null